# How to set target folder for Allure Html report in Behave

Tags: python, python-behave

I was able to generate allure json files using command :

```
behave -f allure_behave.formatter:AllureFormatter -o C:\\Users\\QA\\PycharmProjects\\webAutomationFramework\\allure-results
```

Once I run above command, it run all the feature files of `behave` and generate required .json files into folder `allure-results`

Now when I run the command : `allure serve C:\\Users\\QA\\PycharmProjects\\webAutomationFramework\\allure-results` , it generates allure report proper on some temp URL i.e `http://192.168.0.102:54603/index.html#suites`

Here I want to store this allure HTML report into some specific folder but I don't know how.

I ran below command but that seems to generate the blank report :

```
X:\seleniumlibrary\allure-2.6.0\bin\allure.bat generate "C:\\Users\\QA\\PycharmProjects\\webAutomationFramework\\allure-results-o "C:\\Users\\QA\\PycharmProjects\\webAutomationFramework\\allure-results\\Reports\\LoginReports"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `--alluredir` flag

```
behave -f allure_behave.formatter:AllureFormatter -o C:\\Users\\QA\\PycharmProjects\\webAutomationFramework\\allure-results --alluredir C:\\Users\\QA\\PycharmProjects\\webAutomationFramework\\allure-results\\Reports\\LoginReports
```

Comment: @Guy- Thank you for your help. I do have seems error : `usage: behave [options] [ [DIR|FILE|FILE:LINE] ]+
behave: error: unrecognized arguments: --alluredir`

Comment: @HelpingHands I'm not working with behave (I'm using Pytest), I assumed it will be the same command. Let me check.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @HelpingHands nothing useful, sorry.